# Implementation of PCA for hyper-spectral Image Processing

Tags: computer-vision, pca, sparse-model

I have been studying the concept of PCA and its implementation for dimensionality reduction for more than 1 month. My goal is to classify a hyperspectral image using sparse representation by the linear combination concept  which is as follow:

$$y = Dx$$

So consider $D$ as a dictionary with $d\times  B$ dimension where $d=3000$ is the number of samples and $B=200$ is the number of band/channel.

Now I am trying to construct the $D$ by this mean that the classes (sub-dictionaries) are well separated. Therefore I want to apply PCA to individual sub-dictionary in order to form the main dictionary.

However, my goal is to apply PCA on hyperspectral satellite imagery like [this](https://www.google.com/search?q=hyperspectral%20image&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=YPRSxCEbscaj7M%253A%252C9FJ4kfE_mrjmRM%252C%252Fm%252F0b75x9&usg=AI4_-kQns0ONr5aPanZmuVlFvE1shmvXPA&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiqs4im9OXfAhWFIlAKHW5xAzEQ_h0wD3oECAQQEA#imgdii=OVtmYDMXr8nC5M:&imgrc=N5lbA4hUboCLTM:).

I have implemented the PCA in Octave and project my data on that particular low dimension.  But my question is should I reduce the number of training pixels(observation=d$$) or reduce the variable dimension ($B$)?

Since I use sparse representation and dictionary concept then reducing the dimension of $d$ (observation pixels for individual classes) is more make sense rather than reducing the number of features ($B$). But I am not sure if I am right or not.

After constructing the $D$ should I transform $y$ to PCA dimension before computing its spars coefficients or not?

Comment: typically, PCA selects the principal components from your multi-dimensional signal, i.e. in your case, it reduces $B$ without reducing the number of observation you've got.

Comment: But I manipulate the covariance matrix to have a pairwise pixels evaluation by means of covariance quantity, instead of computing covariance between variables. therefore I am able to compute the eigenvectors and their corresponding eigenvalues for samples (we have lots of reduction vector [pixel])

Comment: that can be presented by A scalar multiplication of another. So lets only use certainty, not uncertainty (in terms of variance of the data).

Comment: The linear algebra five us two amazing concept cal Linearly-Dependent and Linearly-Independent. That is the way we can cover the main info with only the main numbers.